# getting database icon images instead of text name

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file i am trying to edit , but can't get this figured out.

In the database there is a "name" and a "icon" for each client , currently the script pulls the name to insert into the table rows , but i want to replace the text names with the user icons.

Here is existing script

```
tabledata += "<tr class='eventablerow'><td>" + franchiseDatabase['fid_' + fran_id].name + "</td><td title='Posted: " + posted + "'>" + message + "</td></tr>\n";
```

I simply tried to edit this and replace "name" with "icon" , but it gave me the url of the icon , and not the actual image

```
tabledata += "<tr class='eventablerow'><td>" + franchiseDatabase['fid_' + fran_id].icon + "</td><td title='Posted: " + posted + "'>" + message + "</td></tr>\n";
```

**in addition , how can i define a default icon if none are found in the database ?**

The script is being deployed on several servers like so , i would like to be able to have a var set up , so i can insert different default images

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var defaultDisplayMessages = 8;
var hideChatUtilities     = 'false';  // either 'false' or 'true'
var defaultChatDirection   = 'up';   // either 'up' or 'down'
//-->
</script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/chat_with_icons.js"></script>
```

I'd like to put an additional var for the default image here

```
var defaultUserImage = 'img/default-1.jpg';
```

Comment: You need to create an `<img>` tag and paste icon URL there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the url in an `img` tag

```
var defaultUserImage = 'img/default-1.jpg';

tabledata += "<tr class='eventablerow'><td><img src=\"" + (franchiseDatabase['fid_' + fran_id].icon || defaultUserImage) + "\" alt='icon' /></td><td title='Posted: " + posted + "'>" + message + "</td></tr>\n";
```

Comment: Moogs - thanks working perfecly. But for users that have no icons , i am getting "icon" text displaying. How can i install a default icon to display if no icon is found in the database ?

Comment: Moogs , i updated the last portion of my question. I'd like to set up a var where the default image can be changed based on the server its loaded on , while using the same main script file.

Comment: perfect , ty for the edit on that default image , working great !